# TouchesBegan not triggered in UIView as subview of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, addsubview, touchesbegan

I'm creating a custom dropdown menu inside a cell of a UITableView adding this menu as a subview of the cell content view.

When I click on the menu inside the cell I enlarge the view to show all the menu items: now the menu view is over the tableView and all cells.

So, when I select on of the items inside my custom view, the TouchesBegan it's triggered only in the part of the view that's over the UITableView cell in which I call the menu and not in all the view that I enlarged.

If I touch the view in part that is over another cell, the TouchesBegan it's triggered in the cell of the table view and not in the view on top of all cells.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Views typically don't respond to touch events on views or portions of views drawn outside its bounds.  There are a few possible options to fix the issue:

- Enlarge the cell when the dropdown menu is visible to fit the entire menu, but this might negatively impact the visual effect depending on your design.
- Add the menu on the controller instead of the cell view.  If you got this route, you can use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` events from the table view to reposition the menu as the user scrolls the table.  Remember to account for the case where the menu is displayed on the last cell and might overdraw the controller's bounds if always drawn in downward direction.
- Override [`hitTest:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest%3awithEvent%3a) and [`pointInside:withEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside%3awithEvent%3a) on both your menu view and its superview to inform the OS that you respond to events even outside its normal bounds.

Comment: I have temporarily resolve with the first solution you propose.I have tried with override hitTest and pointInsid but every times that I touch the view that I have enlarged over another menu in another cell, the system trigger histTest in the view under my enlarged view.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

Subclass your cell and connect the root view of your layout with the cell:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *rootView;

@end
```

Override hitTest of the cell like this:

```
@implementation CustomCell

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    BOOL res = [self.rootView pointInside:point withEvent:event];
    if(res){
        return [self.rootView hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Now touchesBegin/Move/End/Cancel will be delivered to the view and it's hierarchy whenever touch is inside that view